# pyspark read error when I save data frame in orc format and read that

Tags: pyspark, parquet, orc

I have some data frame I save that dataframe using below code

```
df.write.orc("file:///home/test/path/orc")
```

saving is succcessful it does not give any error but when I read this using

```
df1=spark.read.orc("file:///home/test/path/orc")
```

below is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user1/soft/spark/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
  File "/home/user1/soft/spark/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o24.orc.
: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
mismatched input '.' expecting ':'(line 1, pos 515)

== SQL ==
```

But if I use parquet format to save and read it works fine

```
 df.write.parquet("file:///home/test/path/parquet")
 df1=spark.read.parquet("file:///home/test/path/parquet")
```